# How to create subpartition for Reference-Partitioned Tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

Consider the following scenario of Reference-Partitioned Tables. The table `T_PARTNER_CUSTOMER` borrows partition `part1` and `part2` from table  `T_PARTNER_CONFIG`.

```
CREATE TABLE T_PARTNER_CONFIG (
  ID                   NUMBER(38)                 NOT NULL,
  SECURITY_CONTEXT_ID  NUMBER(38)                 NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST(SECURITY_CONTEXT_ID)
(PARTITION part1 VALUES (0, 1, 2),
 PARTITION part2 VALUES (4, 5, 6));


CREATE TABLE T_PARTNER_CUSTOMER (
  ID                 NUMBER(38)              NOT NULL,
  PARTNER_CONFIG_ID  NUMBER(38)              NOT NULL
  CUSTOMER_NUMBER    VARCHAR2(10)            NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_PC_PARTNER_CONFIG
      FOREIGN KEY(PARTNER_CONFIG_ID) REFERENCES T_PARTNER_CONFIG (id)  
)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE(FK_PC_PARTNER_CONFIG);
```

Now if we want to create further subpartition for table `T_PARTNER_CUSTOMER`, so that the partition `part1` and `part2` are further subdivided for table `T_PARTNER_CUSTOMER`. I tried the approach below, but it doesn't work. I am using Oracle 11g Enterprise edition.

```
CREATE TABLE T_PARTNER_CUSTOMER (
  ID                 NUMBER(38)              NOT NULL,
  PARTNER_CONFIG_ID  NUMBER(38)              NOT NULL
  CUSTOMER_NUMBER    VARCHAR2(10)            NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_PC_PARTNER_CONFIG
      FOREIGN KEY(PARTNER_CONFIG_ID) REFERENCES T_PARTNER_CONFIG (id)  
)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE(FK_PC_PARTNER_CONFIG)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (CUSTOMER_NUMBER) SUBPARTITIONS 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be impossible, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#BABDECCA):

[image]

There is no "SUBPARTITON" clause available, unlike for other partition type, e.g. LIST:

[image]

Comment: You are right, it seems like there is no composite reference partitioning. What could be an alternative solution in this case? List partitioning for `T_PARTNER_CONFIG` and list-hash partitioning for `T_PARTNER_CUSTOMER`.